# Sleep vs tail to wait on process

Tags: process, background-process, tail, sleep

Currently I do:

```
while [ -d "/proc/$PID"  ]; do
  sleep 1
done
```

To wait for a process to exit. If I would replace it with:

```
tail --pid=$PID -f /dev/null
```

Would that be more efficient for the CPU? Or does `tail` just use the same polling under the hood?

Comment: Can you say something more about that particular process? Was it started from the current shell, or via some daemon or in some other shell, and does it belong to the current user?

Comment: @Kusalananda It was started with "set -m" so its not a child of the current script.

Comment: Please don’t cross-post. Choose either here or on Stack Overflow, not both.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the process in the background with `&`, the canonical way is to do

```
process &
wait
```

or

```
process &
pid=$!
wait $pid
```

Comment: That only works for child processes, I start the process with "set -m" so it is not a child, I should have mentioned that.